# Where are browser corner thumbnails stored in Firefox

Tags: firefox, caching

small icons are currently showed in browser corner when I open some web pages, cached images are stored in profile cache folder, but I can't locate corner thumbnails, they do exists but they don't appear in Moz cache viewer.

Comment: can you kindly provide a picture of what you need? It's not clear to me what do you mean by "browser corner on some web pages"?

Comment: [img]https://i.imgur.com/MXo3hAc.png[/img]